# How to import a project into eclipse which is in the given structure

Tags: java, eclipse

I am having a project which is given in the following structure:

[image: structure of project]

I Tried to import it in eclipse but didn't get a way. I tried making a new dynamic web project and replace the src folder in it by the given one but no luck. I get the following output in eclipse:

[image: Outcome]

Could anyone figure out where I am doing it wrong.

Thanks in advance.

As per asked by @TacB0sS I am adding an image of the package Explorer after the said has been done:

[image: Package Explorer]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the **Package Explorer** view's upper bar  there is a small upside down triangle, click on it -> Filters, and deselect them all!

Then edit the .classpath file and change the '*/src*' folder to '*/src/main/java*' 
If you need another source folder, just duplicate the /src line and type your other source folder.

This should solve the problem!

Comment: I deselected all the filter in package explorer and changed the classpath from <classpathentry kind="src" path="/src"/> to  <classpathentry kind="src" path="/src/main/java"/> but it's not helping. My all the packages moved under "Web App Libraries".

Comment: What is inside the webapp packages? resources or sources? Are you using the Java Package Explorer or project explorer? could you post an image of your Package Explorer as well?

Comment: added the image of the package explorer after the said has been done.

Comment: Is seems the sources are not located in the correct folder... I think it is treated as resources... very weird indeed, I would try to keep only the src, first con, and output in your classpath and see what is does... perhaps you have created project not in the correct folder level

Comment: The project that I am using is a standard project downloaded from the spring website and is used as their standard example. It's been build by using maven. I tried to import it as maven project as well but I don't know how to handle maven as I never get a chance to work on that. I am behind a proxy which doesn't allow maven.

Comment: Then why not to try to import it as maven and then fix the project to work without it? Also importing it is not supported?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66388/discussion-between-learner420-and-tacb0ss).

Answer (score 1):

Creating just a new project and adding the sources won't add any missing dependencies to it. The project you are trying to import is probably using some kind of build tool to manage those dependencies. Looking at the [source](https://github.com/svn2github/primefaces-showcase) of primefaces-showcase I can see a `pom.xml`. That means it's using maven. Thus, if you import it as a maven-project in eclipse, it should setup a project with all dependencies.

Comment: you are right @noone, there is one pom.xml. But I am not using maven as I am behind a proxy and I am not able to do that. Isn't there any other way to import the project. I can add the jars manually.

Answer (score 0):

File>Import...>Existing Projects into Workspace
[image]

Comment: I tried it, it says "no projects are found to import". Which I am guessing, its saying because its not able to find any .project and .classpath files in there.